# Determine given Sudoku is a magic square?

Tags: matrix, swap, sudoku

A magic square is a square in which:

1.There is one in the left upper cell.

**2.  There are no repeating numbers in any column.**

**3.  There are no repeating numbers in any row.**

**4.  There are no repeating numbers in any of the smaller squares.**

5.If we swap two smaller squares having a common side, then we obtain square satisfying properties 2 to 4.

Ram has already written several numbers. Determine if it is possible to fill the remaining cells and obtain a magic square.
Example:

**Given Matrix:**

2   1   3   4

4   3   1   2

1   2   4   3

3   4   2   1

Step 1:

Swapping adjacent smaller squares

3   4   1   2

1   2   3   4

2   1   4   3

4   3   2   1

Step 2:

Swapping adjacent smaller squares(Finally obtaining the magic square)

1  2  3  4

3  4  1  2

2  1  4  3

4  3  2  1

Can anyone explain the logic behind this? Please do tell the easiest way to check whether the magic sudoku formation is possible or not for a given matrix?

Comment: As far as i know this question is from some ongoing competition. So please try to solve it by yourself :) all the best.

Comment: @PreethiRao I respect your opinion and successfully solved my problem.

Comment: @dineshjag Give some hints if you did